# How does Python receive stdin and arguments differently?

Tags: python, arguments, stdin

How exactly does Python receive

```
echo input | python script
```

and

```
python script input
```

differently? I know that one comes through stdin and the other is passed as an argument, but what happens differently in the back-end?

Comment: Does `python script input` really work if you didn't use `sys.argv[1]` as the input?

Comment: Okay so let's test. The content of `script` is `print(input())`. Does `echo 'foobar' | python script` just print the output, instead of ask you for the input? And, does `python script 'foobar'` also print the `foobar`, and didn't run the `input()`? Also try `print(__import__('sys').argv[1])`, and check what the output is.

Comment: Weird results. For the first one, it returns an error immediately, and for the second one, it runs the input, then throws an error. For the last one, I think you meant .argv[0]?

Comment: Never mind its argv[1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what is confusing you here. `stdin` and command line arguments are treated as [*two different things*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43489/where-are-command-line-arguments-e-g-some-text-actually-passed-to).

Since you're most likely using CPython (the C implementation of Python) the command line args are passed automatically in the `argv` parameter as with any other `c` program. The `main` function for CPython (located in [`python.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0155eefa8162/Programs/python.c#l18)) receives them:

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)  // **argv <-- Your command line args
{
    wchar_t **argv_copy;   
    /* We need a second copy, as Python might modify the first one. */
    wchar_t **argv_copy2;
    /* ..rest of main omitted.. */
```

While the contents of the pipe are stored in `stdin` which you can tap into via `sys.stdin`.

Using a sample `test.py` script:

```
import sys

print("Argv params:\n ", sys.argv)
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    print("Stdin: \n", sys.stdin.readlines())
```

Running this with no piping performed yields:

```
(Python3)jim@jim: python test.py "hello world"
Argv params:
  ['test.py', 'hello world']
```

While, using `echo "Stdin up in here" | python test.py "hello world"`, we'll get:

```
(Python3)jim@jim: echo "Stdin up in here" | python test.py "hello world"
Argv params:
 ['test.py', 'hello world']
Stdin: 
 ['Stdin up in here\n']
```

---

***Not strictly related, but an interesting note:***

Additionally, I remembered that you can execute content that is stored in  `stdin` by using the **[`-`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/cmdline.html#interface-options)** argument for Python:

```
(Python3)jimm@jim: echo "print('<stdin> input')" | python -
<stdin> input
```

Kewl!

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is python.c?

Comment: The `main` function for CPython, remember, `python` is written in the `c` language.

Comment: Ok I just didn't know that stdin and cmd arguments were treated completely differently, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jim. Though other answers note that **stdin** and **argv** are not equivalent, yours is the first I've found that actually explains why that's the case.