# Passing stdin and argument to script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to pass both stdin(a text file with records), and arguments to a python program.

```
cat names.txt | python myprogram.py 1
```

The code is:

```
#myprogram 

import fileinput,sys
fd = fileinput.input()
for line in fd:
    print line
    print "next\n"
fd.close()
print sys.argv[:] .   #ERROR 

File "test_input.py", line 5, in <module>
 for line in fd:
File "/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 237, in next
 line = self._readline()
File "/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 339, in _readline
 self._file = open(self._filename, self._mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1'
```

When I code separately to capture stdin and arguments, they work.But together, they are giving me an error.

```
#myprogram
import fileinput,sys
fd = fileinput.input()
for line in fd:
    print line
fd.close() .  #command "cat names.txt | python myprogram.py" outputs names

#myprogram
import fileinput,sys
print sys.argv[1] . #Command "python myprogram.py 1"   outputs 1
```

Sorry for such a noob question.According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782307/how-does-python-receive-stdin-and-arguments-differently), both should be independently treated and should work.I couldn't find answer online, hence hoping someone can help me here. Thanks

Comment: `fileinput.input()` will treat `sys.argv[1:]` as files, but you are passing `1` as an argument.

Comment: See the [docs for `fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput), directly under the little code block at the top: "This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:], defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty. "

Comment: @Neo_32 Why are you using `fileinput` at all? Take it out and you have no problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you do interactively import fileinput and help(fileinput) you could get a very well explained answer. I reproduce here the interesting part:

Typical use is:

```
    import fileinput
    for line in fileinput.input():
        process(line)

This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:],
defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty.  If a filename is '-' it
is also replaced by sys.stdin.  To specify an alternative list of
filenames, pass it as the argument to input().  A single file name is
also allowed.
```